# How can one translate English words like "bride-to-be"?

Tags: traduction, anglais, indications-de-temps

There are many other of these kinds of hyphenated words/phrases in English, which signify something or someone that will be a certain thing in the future; for example, "bride-to-be", "mother-to-be", "father-to-be", "movie-to-be", "celebrity-to-be"...

What's the best way to translate these kinds of language constructs into French?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One can translate this with the adjective *futur*:

> La future mariée, une future célébrité, etc…
>   (The future bride, a future celebrity, etc…)

Regarding parents-to-be, it's easier to speak of a *futur papa* or a *future maman* than of a *futur père* or a *future mère*.

*Variants*:

- To refer to future progression (with an air of hope) when the quality being referred to isn't new, one can also use *en devenir*:

  > Un chanteur en devenir
  >   (A singer in the making)
- To refer to a creation phase (possibly a difficult one), the metaphor of *gestation* is frequently used:

  > Un projet en gestation
  >   (A project in gestation)

---

On peut traduire ceux-ci grâce à l'adjectif *futur* :

> La future mariée, une future célébrité, etc…

En particulier, pour les futurs parents, on parlera plus facilement du *futur papa* ou de la *future maman* que du *futur père* ou de la *future mère*.

*Variantes* :

- Pour insister sur le développement progressif (avec une tonalité d'espoir) lorsque la qualité n'est pas nouvelle, on peut aussi utiliser « en devenir » :

  > Un chanteur en devenir
- Pour insister sur une phase de création (éventuellement difficile), la métaphore de la [gestation](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestation) est très courante :

  > Un projet en gestation

Comment: @Jez: There's something special with “mariée”. In French, both *marier* and *mariage* refer to the event (the wedding), therefore “le marié” and “la mariée” usually mean “the groom” and “the bride”. Using standard terminology, “husband” and “wife” are respectively “le mari” and “la femme” (with all the underlying ambiguities).

Answer (score 5):

In the cases when the quality is not present yet, but it isn't even certain when or whether it will develop in the future, you could also use the adjectives *[latent](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/latent)*, *[en puissance](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/puissance)* or *[dormant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dormant)*.

Since you specifically ask about certain cases, it's not really a good answer to your question, but I thought it might be interesting. For an actual answer about certain things, see Stéphane's [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1339) but note that *en devenir* and *en gestation* are also less certain than *futur*, which is the proper translation of *-to-be*.